Please identify Canadian Short Film - Family living in Igloo short on food
Canadian short movie/film, about 10-15 mins. It is about a family in the Arctic that live in their Igloo and are quickly running out of food because there just isn't anything to hunt for some reason. The female daughter decides to go out looking for food, and decides to cross a marking and go beyond where her father tells her never to go. She finds a small village type thing, but all of the buildings are abandoned. She then finds a convenience store to see if there is any food left. 
After a short while, she realizes she is being hunted. Turns out she is being hunted by some futuristic technology flying sphere kind of thing. And we realize the film most likely takes place in the future. She outsmarts the thing and gathers what she can to bring home. 

Though generally a good question, it always helps to add the approximate year of release (or at least when you saw it).

This sounds like the Canadian sci-fi short Frost from 2012.

FROST tells the story of Naya, a young arctic hunter who longs for her father's recognition as a capable disciple. When a season of scarcity threatens their family, she embarks on a perilous search for food beyond the perimeter of their ancestral hunting grounds. Out there at the edge of the ice floes, Naya makes an astonishing discovery: a strange world beyond her ability to comprehend... and a dangerous predator that may be beyond her ability to survive.

Here's the scene in the abandoned convenience store:



